# Current options for Django permissions CBV/DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What are the currently available options for permissions in Django that work for both class-based-views and Django-REST-Framework?

I don't want object-level permissions but rather something like [rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules), [django-rules](https://github.com/maraujop/django-rules), or [dry-rest-permissions](https://github.com/dbkaplan/dry-rest-permissions).

However, the first two appear to be specific to normal views while the second appears to be specific to DRF. I want both.

What are my options if I don't want to duplicate my permission rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `django-rules` already integrates well into the permission system of Django. Thus, `User.has_perm()` works out of the box with it.